# Meaning of what a difference it made

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

SŌSUKE had been relaxing for some time on the veranda, legs comfortably
crossed on a cushion he had set down in a warm, sunny spot. After a while,
however, he let drop the magazine he had been holding and lay down on his
side. It was a truly fine autumn day, the sun bright, the air crisp, and the
clatter of wooden clogs passing through the quiet neighborhood echoed in
his ears with a heightened clarity. Tucking one arm under his head, he cast
his gaze past the eaves at the expanse of clear blue sky above. Compared to
the tiny space he occupied here on the veranda, this patch of sky appeared
extremely vast. **Thinking what a difference it made**, simply to take in the
sky in the rare, leisurely fashion afforded by a Sunday, he squinted directly
at the blazing sun for a few moments, then, averting his eyes, rolled over to
his other side and faced the shoji.

Make a difference mean: have a significant effect on a person or situation.

I think here "what a difference it made" refer to Sosuke and his good feeling after watching the sky. Am I right?

Source: *The Gate* by *NATSUME SŌSEKI* Translated by *WILLIAM F. SIBLEY*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
More specifically, it refers to the clause "simply to take in the sky in the rare, leisurely fashion afforded by a Sunday"
That's what made such a difference to him.